# TypeScript vs JavaScript Language Service

Tags: monaco-editor

The Monaco editor has both a JavaScript and a TypeScript language service, however based on the research and playing I have done they both use the basically the same worker and do virtually the same thing.

What differences exactly does these two "language" services provide.    It appears my TypeScript code works fine in the JavaScript service and of course my JavaScript works fine in the TypeScript language mode.

Through a lot of tests; they actually appear to be the same service, just have two separate configurations.   Can someone confirm that they are the exact same service just two separate configurations; or is there something deeper in the language service that I'm missing.

The purpose for this question is I have a lot of typing's I want to load into the editor; but the user could be using JS or TS, and if they are the same engine; then I'll just put the editor always into TS mode for any JS or TS files to eliminate the massive extra memory that adding duplicate typing's to both engines would entail

Comment: I'm not familiar with Monaco editor, but considering TypeScript is a strict superset of Javascript, it's unsurprising both modes are virtually similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, they are the same - see https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/monaco.contribution.ts

personally I just add them to both. Since monaco is targeted desktops only currently - I'd say that memory is less a problem than having all JS being TS - at least you have to make sure the the TS as JS is on a acceptable ES "level".